# Meteor opening multiple handle on each Subscribe request

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I was trying Meteor and figured out something strange. I was doing experiment with this example mentioned in their docs (I've modified it a bit):

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Counts = new Meteor.Collection("counts");

    // client: subscribe to the count for the current room
    Meteor.subscribe("counts-by-room", '1');

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {

  Messages = new Meteor.Collection("messages");

  Meteor.publish("counts-by-room", function (roomId) {
      var self = this;
      check(roomId, String);
      var count = 0;
      var initializing = true;
      var handle = Messages.find({roomId: roomId}).observeChanges({
       added: function (id) {
          count++;
          if (!initializing)
            self.changed("counts", roomId, {count: count});
        },
        removed: function (id) {
          count--;
          self.changed("counts", roomId, {count: count});
        }
        // don't care about moved or changed
      });



      // Observe only returns after the initial added callbacks have
      // run.  Now return an initial value and mark the subscription
      // as ready.
      initializing = false;
      self.added("counts", roomId, {count: count});
      self.ready();

      console.log("opened new handle");

      // Stop observing the cursor when client unsubs.
      // Stopping a subscription automatically takes
      // care of sending the client any removed messages.
      self.onStop(function () {
        console.log("stopping");
        handle.stop();
      });
    });
}
```

Then I subscribed to the same room multiple times using Chrome Dev Console and on my server console I could see it's opening new handle each time.
Server console:

```
I20130815-14:15:07.470(5.5)? opened new handle
I20130815-14:15:37.661(5.5)? opened new handle
I20130815-14:15:38.616(5.5)? opened new handle
I20130815-14:15:39.191(5.5)? opened new handle
I20130815-14:15:39.703(5.5)? opened new handle
I20130815-14:15:40.215(5.5)? opened new handle
I20130815-14:15:40.711(5.5)? opened new handle
I20130815-14:15:41.207(5.5)? opened new handle
I20130815-14:15:41.704(5.5)? opened new handle
I20130815-14:15:42.200(5.5)? opened new handle
I20130815-14:15:42.696(5.5)? opened new handle
```

I want to know is it normal because in their documentation they say it's very critical to stop an observer. How can I stop it when some one intentionally try to do this. I see this problem as some kind of memory leakage which probably can bring my server down. Am I wrong?

Please help. I'm new to meteor :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry. No matter if you're using Meteor or not, anyone who's evil enough can send many requests to the server hosting your website and make it slow. You can't do much about this. But most users aren't evil and do use your website in your attended way, so if the code you write don't make the server slow, you're pretty safe until you've made some enemies.

One way of not slowing down the server is to close the subscription handles your users no longer needs.